# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' Laravel on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem with laravel and mysql.
It is possible for me to `php artisan migrate` and seed my database. But on the other side accessing to a page using the database is impossible for me. I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000][1698] Access denied for user 'root' @'localhost' (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

My .env is correctly filled in (I can migrate without worries)

My application runs under a ubuntu 18.04.

Does anyone have any idea where this might come from?

Comment: maybe your db_username or db_password is wrong.

Comment: But how would laravel be able to migrate my database without any worries if logins are wrong? :o  I don't really understand what's going on, it's weird.  And I've already check, my logins are correct

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: mysql 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: You should **not** use `root` in your web application; you should create a schema-specific DB user instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `root` user in mysql 5.7 now requires `sudo`.
That means phpMyAdmin will not be able to use `mysql -u root` anymore instead use `sudo mysql -u root` credentials.

What you need to do is create a new user with the same privileges as the `root` credentials and use that instead.

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7/763359#763359) how you can do it.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I didn't know. I thought about it but didn't test it. Now it works!